# Slick.js vertical, center mode, slidesToShow > 5 not working

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I've noticed that there is a problem with slick. I've reproduced it on Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1a8ewgef/16/

HTML:

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
    <div>slide7</div>
    <div>slide8</div>
    <div>slide9</div>
    <div>slide10</div>
    <div>slide11</div>
    <div>slide12</div>
</section>
```

SCSS:

```
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;

.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: $c1;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: $c2;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: false,
    dots: true,
    vertical: true,
    slidesToShow: 7,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true
});
```

And as you see at my fiddle at the beginning slide1 has class slick-center but it is not centered vertically. It should have place like slide3... Could you have solution for that or this is a slick based problem?

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with `centerPadding`. I'm not sure what value should it have, but in example below i think it works pretty well.

I added `centerPadding: "50%"` and also changed `slidesToShow: 7` to `slidesToShow: 3`

```js
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: false,
    dots: true,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "50%"
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: #e84a69;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--              ^
    Use the FORK, Luke.
    create your own new fiddle test case.
-->

<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
    <div>slide7</div>
    <div>slide8</div>
    <div>slide9</div>
    <div>slide10</div>
    <div>slide11</div>
    <div>slide12</div>
    <div>slide13</div>
    <div>slide14</div>
    <div>slide15</div>
    <div>slide16</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not a case ;)
This issue depends on "slidesToShow". It is working good for slidesToShow < 5, but when you take 5 and more it has a problem ;)

Comment: @MateuszPęczkowski Yep, I know it isn't the best solution, but still better then what you had. Well, I don't have a better idea, sorry :)